# Iframe full width and height view problem

Tags: html, css, iframe

I try to use an iframe on the page that covers the whole page. As seen in the following image, its height and width are not 100%. What is the problem?

[image: Using iframe covering whole page]

```html
<iframe style="border: solid 0px;" id="iframe" src="https://www.bing.com/search?q=" width="100%" height="100%">`
```

Comment: Could you provide the code part where this iframe located? It seems like there is another parent element limiting its height.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `height: 100%` won't work! height in percent won't work for items that the parent height depends on the item height. In another way, if parent height is determined exactly, then % will work for children.

In your case, the solution is using `vh` instead of `%`. More information: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

> vh unit: relative to 1% of the height of the viewport*

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.bing.com/search?q=" style="width: 100%; height: 90vh; border: 0;">
```